# FRP frameworks and IO

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

I've just been investigating FRP in Haskell (mainly `reactive-banana` (testimonials!)), and I'm wondering is it common for them, and in case of reactive-banana what's the reason to operate in `IO` monad instead of being constrained to `MonadIO`, or rven better, any `Monad` (so that I could provide own stack)?

It seems to me that's because of focus on GUI programming, where you integrate it with some existing libraries that operate in `IO`? Would it be feasible to change it so that I could integrate it with custom monad stack?

Comment: Good question, I also wondered about why reactive-banana made this decision. Did you take a look at Yampa, they took a different path.

Comment: Nope, not yet. I'm now wondering if I could just brute-force my way through reactive-banana sourcecode and change every IO to `MonadIO m`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking why

```
reactimate :: Frameworks t => Event t (IO ()) -> Moment t ()
```

expects an event with values of type `IO ()` instead of allowing for a custom monad `M ()` with `instance MonadIO M`, then the answer is this:

In practice, custom monad stacks only add state/reader/writer effects to the base `IO` monad. However, in theory, it is entirely possible to add fancy control mechanism like coroutines or non-determinism. I don't know how to integrate the internal state arising from combinators `accumE` with these more general effects, and I have no idea what it means for an event to happen in a non-deterministic context. That's why `reactimate` is restricted to `IO`.

If you have a custom monad stack that is of the state/reader/writer family, then it is usually possible to map it to a pure `IO` computation and use this with `reactimate`. If you find that this doesn't work out (I do think that there might be a problem), I would need a more detailed description of the concrete situation to be able to help.

Comment: Well, my reasoning was such that if you (following the slot machine example) invoke the event using `fire` function which just returns an IO action (and handlers are thus IO actions as well), then it should be possible to do it with other monads. I obviously have no idea about details, so this was just my hunch...

Comment: Well, you can always use `liftIO` when you invoke an event with `fire`, if that's what you mean.